# ADO.NET | Что будет с соединением после using?

Tags: c#, ado.net

В инициализации команды создаю копию подключения, т.к. данный Reader находиться внутри ещё одного Reader, а на одно и тоже подключение в них он жалуется. 
Вопросы следующие:
1) Что будет с подключением, созданным методом CreateConnectionByFingerprint()? (В методе подкчюление откроется, а как быть с закрытием?)
2) Если ли ещё какой-то способ использования двух ридеров одним подключением?

```
            using (var Reader = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT id FROM [таблица] WHERE id = N'{Id}'", SqlTool.CreateConnectionByFingerprint(Con, true, true)).ExecuteReader()) {
                while (Reader.Read()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Оберните в using вызов CreateConnectionByFingerprint() в переменную и тогда вопросы потеряют актуальность

Comment: Можно вынести новое подключение в using (var TmpCon = CreateConnection...), но хотелось бы оставить этот метод в строке инициализации

Comment: Если Вы хотите "контролировать" время "жизни" соединения, то Вы на правильном пути, в противном случае у Вас нет гарантий, что Вы не достигнете лимита подключений

Comment: А что вообще в целом происходит с этим подключением? Существует ли какой-то способ автоматического закрытия соединения Reader`а, если сам Reader закрывается?

Comment: Вы можете сказать, что делается в **SqlTool.CreateConnectionByFingerprint**? Что такое **Con**? Тот кто вызвал создание, тот и вызывает освобождение ресурсов. Теоретически вы можете сделать то что, хотите, но внутри  Reader Connection объявлен следующим образом `protected SqlConnection Connection { get; }`

Comment: _"Существует ли какой-то способ автоматического закрытия соединения Reader-а, если сам Reader закрывается?"_ да, это можно указать параметром: `new SqlCommand(...).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)`